# Spring boot application monitoring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, admin, spring-boot-actuator

I am working on a tool to monitor spring boot applications. In our environment, we have some 15 different spring boot apps running. I want to implement a UI which would provide the statuses of these applications without someone logging into servers. A quick google search found me the following options:

1. Spring boot admin
2. Discovery client/server

I have done the POCs for both of these and it seems they both need client applications (to be monitored) to have a dependency added into pom file as well as configuration properties (Discovery may have an option where discovery client scans the registry but I couldn't make it work). Now, even though I can add the maven dependencies, I don't really want to do that as there are many apps. Do we have any alternate way of 'magically detecting' all the running spring boot app on a server and show them somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the auto discovery and subscription option is just one of a huge number of details to work out.   Trying to do it your self will be very frustrating as you have to work out and manage tons of details around DNS, ports, environments, statistics, monitoring, deployments, spinning up new containers, and a LOT more.

If you really need to do this I would start Googling for "Micro service Containers" and look into the existing options.  Cloud Foundry seems to be the most popular one a lot of shops seem to have gone to, but there are a number of options.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think SpringBootAdmin needs a dependency to be added anywhere in the client application to be monitored. Please refere to the following post to get an idea about how to setup SBAP for dynamically discovering and monitoring SpringBoot services [Spring Boot Admin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905356/spring-boot-admin-page?rq=1).